# Fix/avoid/ignore recursive reference error?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ilmerge

I need two class libraries that reference each other.
Why? One is compiled in C# and the other in VB.NET.

It would be better if I could somehow merge the assemblies programmatically, without requiring external programs or even the extended framework.

Comment: I would vote Avoid. This is a terrible setup.

Comment: I would loved to provide hybrid language assemblies in my little IDE. But... >.>

Comment: Tou should split of a 3rd assembly to break the dependencies. In whatever languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your assemblies via assembly linker tool into multimodule assembly.
For example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/07/15/183813.aspx

Comment: I finally understand how to do it. Unfortunately, it's not the right thing for me. But it's the right answer for a generic assembly.